# iSCSIネームについて

Tags: network

現在仮想化基礎検定という資格を取得するため学習しています。
ここで質問するのが場違いでしたらすみません。

IP-SANにおいては、iSCSIプロトコルを用いてファブリックデバイス間の
通信を行う場合、機器を一意特定するためにiSCSIネームをデバイスに
付与します。

iSCSIプロトコルでは下位レイヤーでTCP/IPが使われていますが、
TCP/IPまでで機器を一意に特定することはできないのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答お願いします。

Comment: 簡単に説明すると、iSCSIネームをわざわざ付ける理由は、設置場所（IPアドレス）が変更されてもネットワーク上で同じデバイスが識別出来るようにデバイス固有のiSCSIネームが付いています。

Comment: IPアドレスの変更があってもiSCSIネームさえあれば通信が可能ということでしょうか？名前とIPアドレスを紐付けているサービスがどこかで稼働していれば、になりそうですが。。　名前解決用といった側面もあると認識しました。コメントありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、回答です。
＞TCP/IPまでで機器を一意に特定すること
iSCSIプロトコルを使いノード識別や管理を行っているので　出来ません。
IPアドレスの変更があったら設定も変更します。
（SCSIコマンドをIPパケットに乗せて運んでいるだけなので、また、IPを使用していますが、ファイルサーバとは違い 出来るなら閉塞した環境で使う物です。）

・簡単に何故必要なのか

ノード識別や管理のためにiSCSIネームを持ち,iSCSIプロトコルを用いて サーバやPC（イニシエータ）が HDDなどのデバイス（ターゲット）との間でTCPコネクションを張り、認証とネゴシエーションすることによりデータ転送を行います　認証は、不正アクセス、なりすましなどを防ぐためです。

補足、以下の様にiSCSIネームの命名は決められています。

iSCSIネームは、iSCSIノードのロケーションに依存しないこと、全世界で唯一であること、iSCSIノードのライフにおいて固定であることなどが必要であり、
iSCSIでは、IPドメイン名を使用したiSCSI Qualified NameとIEEEの64ビットExtended Unique Identifierを使用した「IEEE EUI-64 Format」でiSCSIネームを付ける。（管理上必要ならエイリアス名を付けます。）

補足２、規格名など

SCSI（スカジー　＜−ふざけてはいません、SCSIはスカジーと読みます）バス（ケーブル）接続でHDD､テープデバイスなどを繋ぐ規格があります。（転送速度は、〜1280Mbps）

SAN　（サン）　シリアルSCSIプロトコルを用いてネットワーク化した規格です。（転送速度は光ファイバを使って800Mbpsぐらい、導入コストが高いので普通の人は手が出せません。）

iSCSI（アイスカジー）は、SCSIコマンドをIPパケットに乗せてデータ転送を行う規格です。（ギガビットイーサネットで、実用的に使えるようになった。でも古い規格です。）

Comment: http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fnetwork/tokusyuu/16iscsi/iscsi02.html の抜粋の継ぎ接ぎに見えます

Comment: > suzukisさん　stackoverflowのサービス上抜粋がアウトということでしょうか？そうでなければ抜粋でも疑問が解決しさえすれば問題ないです。(私は、ですが)　コメントありがとうございました。

Comment: > yyzさん　確かにTCP/IPだけではなりすまし等の恐れがあり、一意特定できる保証がありませんね。閉塞した環境で使うならそこまで気にすることでもないのでは、とも思いましたが。。(元々は閉塞環境で使う前提で作ってなかったのかもしれませんが)　多段的に機器の特定を行うためにiscsiネームを用いての認証が必要となるのですね。ご回答ありがとうございました。